# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase

I getting this error in Crashlytics "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference" I don't know where the issue is in code. Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Here is my code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        setBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setBackground);

        Glide.with(this).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("images")).into(imageView);

        setBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setBackgroundImage();
            }
        });
    }


    private void setBackgroundImage() {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        WallpaperManager manager =  WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set Wallpaper Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper not load yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Layout code, I added code for more information on the issue

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setBackground"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        android:background="@drawable/setback"
        android:text="@string/set_as_background"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_condensed"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.546"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.958" />
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file as well?

Comment: ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()) returns null, right?